# Custom URL protocol handler Qt 5

Tags: qt, url, qml, qt-quick, qiodevice

I want to use a `Video`/`MediaPlayer` QML element in my app, and have it play a video from a custom stream. `QMediaPlayer` seems to support this since you can tell it to read from a `QIODevice` which can do anything you want. But `MediaPlayer` only supports a URL.

Is there any way I can register my own URL scheme that uses my own streaming protocol? For example, say I wanted to make `rtsp2://...`, could I do something vaguely like:

```
class Rtsp2 : public QIODevice
{
    // open, read, seek, close, etc.
}

QCoreApplication::registerUrlProtocol("rtsp2", Rtsp2);
```

Comment: Handeling urls is os specifick.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at the details, but the QML engine has a QNetworkAccessManager it uses for connectivity. You can add your own protocols at the QNAM layer by subclassing and hooking createRequest. However I suspect QMediaPlayer might not uses this QNAM for media loading, because the underlying media layer often provides its own IO abstraction.

(Also, adding custom protocols to QNAM isn't exactly trivial - ideally it would be a simple 'registerProtocolFor' call but sadly this is not the case)